# Would logical replication will allow me to merge 2 database into differenct schemas?

Tags: postgresql

In my case I have 2 postgresql databases:

1. App1
2. App2

Both of them are hosted into a single RDS instance and both of them have one schema named `public`. Both of databases have different table names.

The reason I want to do this, is because both App1 Db and App2 db have foreighn tables that refer into each other. By merging them I will be able to place more integrity checks so my data between App1 and App2 will be robust.

And I want to be able to combine them into a new database with 0 downtime. Each database has only one schema `public`. And what I want to do is to transfer the App2 database into a new schema named `app2` at App1 database.

The problem is that in App2 I have a continious stream of critical data and active applications that run on it.

So I thought using logical replication between App2.public -> App1.app2. Then I will setup the App2 to be a publisher and App1 to be a subscriber.

The way I thought to do is to use the following approach:

1. Do a complete dump of App2 excluding all foreign tables
2. Setup a local db in my PC and importing the dump in it
3. Rename the schema from `public` into `app2`
4. Perform a new pgdump from my local database
5. Import it into the App1 Database
6. Then I setup App2 as a publisher and the App1 as a subscriber.
7. Then change the connection info on existing Applications to use the App1 database

The way I need to do this is not to cause a downtime to existing apps connected into App2 database. What I want to do is gradually to depricate the App2 database but not on one-go in order to avoid disruptions in my existing applications.

Both of them run Postgresql 11.

The question I want to ask is:

1. Can I replicate 2 different schemas if not can I set a schema 'alias' in App2 database and rename the App2 schema into another name.
2. Would existing data from App2 Db will be transfered into App1 database?
3. How I can know when App2 existing data has completely been transfered into App1 database?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, because currently the names of the schema, the table and the columns have to be identical on the publisher and the subscriber.  So you cannot have a different schema name on the replica.

Comment: But I can rename on the master the schema before replicating right. I mean if I rename the `public` schema into `app2` and then replicate the App2 database into App1 will it work?

Comment: Sure, that should work.